# Get 2 or more different informations from a SQL-database (from different tables)

Tags: c#, sql

Im trying to get different informations from different tables with 1 SQL-connection.
The actual code is:

```
sql_Verbindung.MssqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT USER, PWD FROM " + server + ".[dbo].[table1] where USER = '12345'";
            sql_Verbindung.OpenConnection();
            sql_Verbindung.MssqlReader = sql_Verbindung.MssqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (sql_Verbindung.MssqlReader.HasRows)
            {
                while (sql_Verbindung.MssqlReader.Read())
                {
                    object.Name = sql_Verbindung.MssqlReader["USER"].ToString().Trim();
                    object.Passwort = sql_Verbindung.MssqlReader["PWD"].ToString().Trim();
                }
            }
            sql_Verbindung.CloseConnection();

            sql_Verbindung.MssqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + server + ".[dbo].[table2]";
            sql_Verbindung.OpenConnection();
            sql_Verbindung.MssqlReader = sql_Verbindung.MssqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (sql_Verbindung.MssqlReader.Read())
            {
                if (sql_Verbindung.MssqlReader["Live"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    object.database_available = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    object.database_available = false;
                }
            }
            sql_Verbindung.CloseConnection();
```

This works but I think it could be a lot better.
(The SQL.open and SQL.close obviously open and close the connection.)
And how can I get both informations without closing the conenction in between? If I try using the same code without closing the connection it crashes.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: For your second query, there does not appear to be any `WHERE` clause.  Assuming, then, the second query would return more than 1 record, how do you want to retrieve both result sets in one go?

Comment: What relationship exist between the two tables? If you want to keep the connection open then you need to close the _sql_Verbindung.MssqlReader_ before using again the connection

Comment: And I hope that you don't get that _server_ variable from a user input

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to get resultset of two table from the same database why don't you use Union.

```
SELECT USER, PWD, NULL AS LIVE FROM " + server + ".[dbo].[table1] where USER = '12345'
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS USER, NULL AS PWD, Live  FROM " + server + ".[dbo].[table2]
```

Improvement area.

- Use store-procedures if possible to avoid sql injection.
- If still you want to use inline query then try to use query like mentioned above, instead making multiple round trips to database.